# cannot import name 'IncorrectSchemaTypeError while running airflow initdb

Tags: airflow

I'm running with:

```
ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
python 3.6.9
```

I install aitflow with:

```
pip install apache-airflow
```

and tried to init the db:

```
airflow initdb
```

And get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 26, in <module>
    from airflow.bin.cli import CLIFactory
  File "/home/ubadmin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 71, in <module>
    from airflow.www_rbac.app import cached_app as cached_app_rbac
  File "/home/ubadmin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/www_rbac/app.py", line 27, in <module>
    from flask_appbuilder import AppBuilder, SQLA
  File "/home/ubadmin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .api import ModelRestApi  # noqa: F401
  File "/home/ubadmin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/api/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from marshmallow_sqlalchemy.fields import Related, RelatedList
  File "/home/ubadmin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .schema import TableSchemaOpts, ModelSchemaOpts, TableSchema, ModelSchema
  File "/home/ubadmin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/schema/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .sqlalchemy_schema import (
  File "/home/ubadmin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/schema/sqlalchemy_schema.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ..exceptions import IncorrectSchemaTypeError
ImportError: cannot import name 'IncorrectSchemaTypeError
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: yes. I'm getting the following error: "ImportError: cannot import name 'resolve_types''

Answer (score 3):

Got the same failure.

Fixed it by reinstalling airflow with contraints, like mentioned in the official docs: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/installation.html

```
AIRFLOW_VERSION=1.10.12
PYTHON_VERSION="$(python --version | cut -d " " -f 2 | cut -d "." -f 1-2)"
CONSTRAINT_URL="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-${AIRFLOW_VERSION}/constraints-${PYTHON_VERSION}.txt"

# For example: 3.6
# https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints1.10.12/constraints-3.6.txt

pip install "apache-airflow==${AIRFLOW_VERSION}" --constraint "${CONSTRAINT_URL}"
```